# Syntax Error in NDSolve Code

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve the motion equations for the Trojan Asteroids in Sun-Jupiter system. However, i am getting this error

**Syntax: '(' cannot be followed by 'x[t],y[t]'**

in this code

```
Alpha = 0.000953875;
r_1 = Sqrt[(x - Alpha)^2 + y^2];
r_2 = Sqrt[(x + 1 - Alpha)^2 + y^2];
x_0 = -0.509;
y_0 = 0.883;
u_0 = 0.0259;
v_0 = 0.0149;


NDSolve[
    {x'[t] == u[t],

    y'[t] == v[t],

    u'[t] == -(1 - Alpha) (x[t] - Alpha)/r_1 (x[t],  y[t])^3 - Alpha (x[t] + 

    1 - Alpha)/r_2(x[t], y[t])^3 + x[t] + 2 v[t],

    v'[t] == -(1 - Alpha) y[t]/r_1 (x[t], 

    y[t])^3 - Alpha y[t]/r_2 (x[t], y[t])^3 + y[t] - 2 u[t],

    x[0] == x_0, y[0] == y_0, 

    u[0] == u_0, v[0] == v_0},

    {x, y, u, v}, {t, 0, t_max}]
```

Of course, i am extremely average at coding, so any kind of help will suffice

Thanks

Comment: The `_` has a predefined meaning in MMA. Try removing all those that you have used inside variable names and see how much that helps.

Comment: My advice is to learn the basics before trying to do something complicated: [go through a tutorial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/12). Here you started to *guess* at the syntax (instead of looking it up), and of course not every guess was correct. At this stage, it's too early to ask questions on Mathematica.SE. Please make sure you have at least a basic understanding of the language before you ask.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the advice, i will definitely study basics before trying more complex things

Answer (score 2):

In addition to _ there is still a misuse of functions in () instead of []

```
Alpha = 0.000953875;
r01[x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x - Alpha)^2 + y^2];
r02[x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x + 1 - Alpha)^2 + y^2];
x00 = -0.509;
y00 = 0.883;
u00 = 0.0259;
v00 = 0.0149;
tmax = 100;

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == u[t], y'[t] == v[t], 
   u'[t] == -(1 - Alpha) (x[t] - Alpha)/r01[x[t], y[t]]^3 - 
     Alpha (x[t] + 1 - Alpha)/r02[x[t], y[t]]^3 + x[t] + 2 v[t], 
   v'[t] == -(1 - Alpha) y[t]/r01[x[t], y[t]]^3 - 
     Alpha y[t]/r02[x[t], y[t]]^3 + y[t] - 2 u[t], x[0] == x00, 
   y[0] == y00, u[0] == u00, v[0] == v00}, {x, y, u, v}, {t, 0, tmax}];

    ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: fig1]